# В каких строчках кода есть ошибки? (11 строк)

Tags: python

Я новичок в Питоне, прохожу тестирование, споткнулся на этом вопросе. В коде ниже допущены ошибки. Нужно найти где.

```
def make_list(number):
    names = []
    for item in number:
        names.append(input("Введите имя с заглавной буквы"))
    print(names)

number = int(input("Сколько имен надо ввести?"))
names = make_list(number)
for name in names:
    if name[1] == "А":
        print("Имя", name, "начинается с буквы А")
```

Прогонял чрез онлайн компиляторы, выдавало ошибку в 3 и 7 строках, но это Не верный ответ (так ругается тест)

Задача:
Программа запрашивает у пользователя сначала количество имён, потом - имена, и формирует из них список.
Из этих имён на экран выводятся только те, которые начинаются с заглавной буквы "А".

Comment: `name[1]` это не первая, а вторая буква, нумерация начинается с нуля

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `!` - Ошибка
> `*` - Коментарий

```py
def make_list(number):
    # * names определено и здесь и на уровне модуля
    #    не ошибка но лучше так не делать, чтобы не путаться
    names = []
    # * Использование именованной переменной `item` без ее дальнейшего использования
    #     Обычно в таких случаях используется `_`
    # ! Переменная number имеет тип int (no Iterable) 
    #   поэтому для создания цикла здесь должно быть `range(number)`
    for item in number:
        names.append(input("Введите имя с заглавной буквы"))
    print(names)
    # ! Функция не возвращает names поэтому names на уровне модуля будет всегда None

number = int(input("Сколько имен надо ввести?"))
names = make_list(number)

# ! Поскольку names всегда None а None not Iterable 
#    то попытка итерировать по этой переменной вызовет исключение
for name in names:
    # ! Первая буква name будет иметь индекс 0 а не 1
    if name[1] == "А":
        print("Имя", name, "начинается с буквы А")
```

Вот так должно работать

```py
def make_list(number):
    names = []
    for _ in range(number):
        names.append(input("Введите имя с заглавной буквы"))
    return names

qty = int(input("Сколько имен надо ввести?"))
name_list = make_list(qty)
for name in name_list:
    if name[0] == "А":
        print("Имя", name, "начинается с буквы А")
```

" Фантазия на тему..."

```py
for name in [
    input("Введите имя с заглавной буквы: ")
    for _ in range(int(input("Сколько имен надо ввести? ")))
]:
    if name.startswith('А'):
        print("Имя", name, "начинается с буквы А")
```